# Qualitative Measurement

Tags: single-word-requests

If a measurement is a quantitative observation, then what is the word for a qualitative observation?

> Measurement: 1 cup
>
> X: smells old

Comment: Maybe you're looking for **assessment**?

Comment: Note that you can also have qualitative measurements as well. Measurements are not always quantitative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said it in the question. The word is **observation**. It was your observation that X smelled old. This usage is common in chemistry.

As in:

- 2 ounces were measured.
- A pink flame was observed.
- A pungent odour was observed.
- Write down your observations during the experiment.

---

Here's Wikipedia's description of the [flame test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_test), which calls for "qualitative measurent"

> The test involves introducing a sample of the element or compound to a hot, non-luminous flame, and **observing** the color of the flame that results.

Also see: [Observations and Measurements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observations_and_Measurements) (Wikipedia)

Comment: +1, should be accepted. Qualitative means without determining a value. You might simply be doing a comparison, or making observations.

Comment: Yes, I came to this conclusion as well. What threw me off is how the OpenEHR Archetype definition works. 

"Observations are the 'uninterpreted' or raw information - ie the clinical observations or 'the evidence' - which includes anything reported by the patient as a symptom, event or concern; examination findings; and measurements/test results.
 Thus an OBSERVATION is used when the information is derived from a direct observation, measurement, or experience of the patient or data subject."

Answer (score 1):

I would use *[assessment](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/assessment)* or *opinion* depending on the context.

> - The act of assessing; appraisal. (AHD)

Comment: assessment as well as appraisal are quantitative a lot of times

Answer (score 0):

**Description**   (free Dictionary on-line)

> 1. The act, process, or technique of describing.

**Evaluation**

> the making of a judgement about the amount, number, or value of
>   something; assessment.